# How do I get cookie from apollo graphql resolver?

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I can set cookie in client, but I don't know how to get cookies from server reslover (apollo graphql.)

// resolver.js

```
export const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    async getSinglePost(_, args, context) {

        // "context.req.headers.cookies" are empty. d
        // Even if setting "credentials: 'include' " in creating Apollo client chche.   
    },
  },
```

// apolloClient.js

```
new ApolloClient({
    ssrMode: Boolean(ctx),
    link: authLink.concat(new HttpLink({
      uri: 'http://localhost:4000/graphql', // Server URL (must be absolute)
      credentials: 'same-origin', // Additional fetch() options like `credentials` or `headers`
      fetch,
    })),
    cache: new InMemoryCache({ fragmentMatcher }).restore(initialState),
    credentials: 'include',
  })
```

Am I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that this has to do something with Apollo Server itself, because assuming you use express, the `req` object is passed directly into context and isn't modified by Apollo at all.

Instead i would check, if you even parse the cookies. For that, it is recommended to use [cookie-parser lib](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-parser) and run it as a middleware.

Also, the cookie object should be then in `req.cookies`(not in `req.headers.cookies`)

Comment: `cookieParser` middleware is already set... I am miss something... I don't know what it is.

Comment: My graphql server is running at port `4000` and my nextjs client running at port `3000`. I can get client cookie with express router but cannot get it in graphql resolver.

Comment: Seems like an issue with Apollo: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/issues/1791. @Juntae found any work arounds?

Comment: I switched from `apollo-server` to `apollo-server-express` and configured my own Express instance using cookie parser middleware. Only then did it work. I can now access same-domain cookies using `context.req.cookies`